# Start a form before launching an XNA Game

Tags: c#, winforms, xna

So I created a form with a browser to the "News" page on my game's site. It has 2 buttons: "Start Game" and "Level Editor".

I am currently using `DialogResult` to check if any of these buttons was clicked - "Start Game" has `DialogResult = Yes` and "Level Editor" has `DialogResult = No`. Yeah, that's an ugly solution but I couldn't make it work with `Application.Run(newsForm);` because I did not know how to check for button clicks outside of the `newsForm` class.

Program.cs of my XNA project:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    using (var newsForm = new NewsForm())
    {
        if (newsForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            using (var game = new Game1())
            {
                game.Run();
            }
            newsForm.Dispose();
        }
        else if (newsForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.No)
        {
            using (var editor = new EditorForm())
            {
                Application.Run(editor);
                newsForm.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my `NewsForm` designer I set the `DialogResult` property of the buttons to the appropriate value. But I have another problem:

When I click on "Start Game" the XNA form shows properly and the `NewsForm` is closed. But when I click on "Level Editor" the form looks like it closes and then reopens... I have to click the button again to start the `editor` form. And if I click on "Start Game" it closes. I'm sure that's caused by the `DialogResult`.

As I said above, the way I'm doing it is definitely not the correct one design-wise, because:

1. It's a form, not a dialog
2. The buttons don't mean what the `DialogResult` or the user expects them to mean

So if you have any idea how I can achieve what I describe above, with or (preferably) without `ShowDialog`, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `switch()` instead of `if()`:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    using (var newsForm = new NewsForm())
    {
        DialogResult dr = newsForm.ShowDialog();
        switch (dr)
        {
            case DialogResult.Yes:
                using (var game = new Game1())
                {
                    game.Run();
                    newsForm.Close();
                    newsForm.Dispose(); // since you open the form with ShowDialog(), you must dispose of it manually.
                }
                break;
            case DialogResult.No:
                using (var editor = new EditorForm())
                {
                    Application.Run(editor);
                    newsForm.Close();
                    newsForm.Dispose(); // since you open the form with ShowDialog(), you must dispose of it manually.
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```